# SSRS 2008 Expression: Combine two IIF condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is this possible?

I have this expression to hide the textbox if the PageNumber is not equals to 1.

```
=IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 1, FALSE, TRUE)
```

then I have this another expression. This hide the textbox if the Key value is null.

```
=IIF(Parameters!Key.Value <> "", False, True)
```

I want to combine the two conditions but can't figure it out how.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use nested if condition:

```
=IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 1,IIF(Parameters!Key.Value <> "",False,True),TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks.. I also edited your answer for another possible way of doing it.